# Trying to create a Jenkins docker container using chocolatey in a windows container

Tags: powershell, docker, jenkins, dockerfile, windows-container

I've looked at a few questions, but I couldn't find anything that matched my issue. If this is a duplicate, I apologize!

Currently, I'm trying the create a Jenkins docker container using chocolatey inside a dockerfile script. My current script is the following

```
# escape=`

# Microsoft ISO required for building Empower
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore:ltsc2019

SHELL ["cmd", "/S", "/C"]

# Install Chocolatey on the docker container
RUN powershell -Command `
    "Set-ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Scope Process -Force; `
    [System.Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [System.Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol -bor 3072; `
    iex ((New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadString('https://chocolatey.org/install.ps1'))"

# Install Jenkins
RUN powershell -Command `
    "choco install -y jenkins"
```

This built fine, and produced me the following image, which I've tried to add a run command to

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                    CREATED             STATUS                      PORTS               NAMES
1b18ae2b6432        724f89147e6f        "-p 8080:8080"             3 minutes ago       Created                                         docker_jenkins
```

Unfortunately, this errors with the following, when starting the container

```
Error response from daemon: container 1b18ae2b64329c57953b81c1fba2c3f95836f3ae0a77affe0b00bbcd18ef1125 encountered an error during hcsshim::System::CreateProcess: failure in a Windows system call: The system cannot find the file specified. (0x2)
[Event Detail:  Provider: 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000]
[Event Detail:  Provider: 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000]
[Event Detail: onecore\vm\compute\management\orchestration\vmhostedcontainer\processmanagement.cpp(173)\vmcomputeagent.exe!00007FF73DE39D2B: (caller: 00007FF73DDEE13A) Exception(2) tid(39c) 80070002 The system cannot find the file specified.
    CallContext:[\Bridge_ProcessMessage\VmHostedContainer_ExecuteProcess]
 Provider: 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000] extra info: {"CommandLine":"-p 8080:8080","WorkingDirectory":"C:\\","CreateStdInPipe":true,"CreateStdOutPipe":true,"CreateStdErrPipe":true,"ConsoleSize":[0,0]}
Error: failed to start containers: docker_jenkins
```

I can't quite tell what's going wrong. Any information on the matter would be greatly appreciated. I'm quite new to docker and containers, so I apologize if this is a silly question!

Comment: I am getting a very similiar error with different event details. Maybe that is just because I am running another image. Did you already find a solution to this? Can you please share some information on your operating system and the output of "docker version"

Comment: @rominator007 - Try what I've put as an answer. I ended up fixing this issue and progressing with my dockerfile, so the below is a small snippet of the overall dockerfile.

Comment: Thanks. I do not have the need for a Dockerfile. In fact it would be cumbersome in my environment. In the meantime I found out that I was having an issue where the container would start with docker run <image> but not with docker run <image> --name <name>. Turned out you have to start it with docker run --name <name> <image> *facepalm*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to solve this issue. The following dockerfile is what I ended up with

```
# escape=`

# Microsoft ISO required for building Empower
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore:ltsc2019

# Update shell to powershell
SHELL ["powershell", "-command"]

# Install Chocolatey on the docker container
RUN Set-ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Scope Process -Force; `
    [System.Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [System.Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol -bor 3072; `
    iex ((New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadString('https://chocolatey.org/install.ps1'))

# Install Jenkins
RUN choco install -y jenkins
```